# A Question about the Intersection Multiplicity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In a recent lecture the lecturer defined the **local ring** of an irreducible affine variety $V$ at $P\in V$ as
$$
\mathcal{O}_{V,P}=\{\phi\in K(V)\mid\phi\text{ is defined at }P\}. 
$$
Then he defined the **intersection multiplicity** of two polynomials $f,g\in K[x,y]$ to be 
$$
I_P(f,g)=\dim\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2,P}/\langle f,g\rangle,
$$
where $\langle f,g\rangle$ is the ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2,P}$ generated by $f,g$.

My question is that what the above definition means? It is a 'dimension', but of what object? A vector space or an affine space or something else? And if the definition is clear, what does the phrase 'intersection multiplicity' mean? I mean, how does this definition relate to the actual meaning of 'intersection'? This quite confuses me so could anyone help me with this?

Comment: The dimension is as a $K$ vector space. Let $C$ be a curve in $\mathbb{A}^2$ and let $L$ be a line in $\mathbb{A}^2$ such that $C$ and $L$ intersect at $p$ and $L$ is tangent to $C$ at $p$. Then there intersection is not just a point but includes also a tangent direction thus the intersection multiplicity is at least 2 (try to workout an example and draw a picture).

Comment: @user45150 but why is it a $K$ vector space? Is it always finite dimensional?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2,P}$ is a $K$ vector space (if a function is defined at $P$ then if you multiply it by any scalar it should still be defined). From this you it follows $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2,P}/(f,g)$ is $K$-vector space.

Comment: To address your second question, no it is not always finite dimensional (for instance what happens if $P$ is the origin and $f=x,g=x^2$), but it will always be if $f$ and $g$ are coprime to each other.